# useState is not updating the DOM in my React todo list app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn the basics of React and thought that making a todo list app would be a great first project to help me learn.

I have a basic form to add todos, but, when enter is clicked, the DOM does not change. Here is my app.js code, which I think is where my error might be:

```
import AddTodoForm from './components/AddTodoForm.js';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList.js';
import { dataList } from './components/AddTodoForm.js';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const[list, setList] = useState([]);

  function update(){
    setList(dataList);
    console.log(list);
    console.log("update function has run.")
  }

  return (
    <div>

      <AddTodoForm update = {update} />

      <h1>My Todos</h1>
        
      <TodoList todos={list} />    

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the code for TodoList.js as somebody had asked for it:

```js
import Todo from './Todo';

function TodoList(props) {
    return (
        <ul>
            {props.todos.map((todo) => (
                <Todo
                key = {todo.id}
                id= {todo.id}
                text= {todo.text}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default TodoList;
```

here is the AddTodoForm.js:

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';


var idCounter = 1;

export const dataList = [];

function AddTodoForm(props){

    const titleInputRef = useRef();


    function submitHandler(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        const enteredTitle= titleInputRef.current.value;

        const todoData = {
            text: enteredTitle,
            id: idCounter,
        }

        idCounter++;

        console.log(todoData);
        dataList.push(todoData);

       
        
    }


    return (
        <div className="card">
            <h2>Add New Todos</h2>

            <form onSubmit={(event) => {submitHandler(event); }}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="text">New Todo: </label>
                    <input type="text" required id="text" ref={titleInputRef}></input>
                </div> <br />

                <div>
                    <button className="btn" onClick = {props.update}>Add Todo</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default AddTodoForm;
```

I have checked the log and the update function runs. Also, if I make a slight change to my code, the todos I had entered will appear on the screen but I am not sure why the DOM does not change when the update function runs.

This is my first post on here so I wasn't sure how much of my code to include. Please ask if you need the code from my other components.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please share what `TodoList` is doing with `todos`?

Comment: Also, what slight change are you making that makes the todos appear on your screen?

Comment: I am not react guy, Did you forget to import `import React from 'react'`?

Comment: Is `dataList` a predefined list of todos (array of objects?), and you want to import and display them, and also add to them with new todo information added through the form?

Comment: It might help if you can create a [mre], it's preferred if you can use a react [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support), or if it's too hard to do that then you can make a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have edited the post to show what TodoList does. Basically, it just displays a list of all the todos. By slight changes, I just meant adding a space or backspace and saving makes the app display the todos as intended.

Comment: Okay, could you show `AddTodoForm` with this `dataList` as @Andy asked?

Comment: dataList starts as an empty array but objects can be added to it using the form. Information is added to the dataList as expected but the DOM is not updated

Comment: I have added AddTodoForm to my post :)

Comment: Thanks @George! I pasted an answer; check it and let me know please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `dataList.push(todoData)` won't change `dataList` itself, only its content, and React doesn't check the content to update the DOM. You could use the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to have a completely new `dataList`.

You could even get rid of that `dataList`, and use the empty array given to `useState`. Update your `update` function slightly, and it should work:

```
import AddTodoForm from "./components/AddTodoForm.js";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList.js";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  function update(text) {
    // this is for learning; consider using a proper id in real world
    setList([...list, { text: text, id: list.length + 1 }]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <AddTodoForm update={update} />
      <h1>My Todos</h1>
      <TodoList todos={list} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import { useRef } from "react";

function AddTodoForm(props) {
  const titleInputRef = useRef();

  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.update(titleInputRef.current.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>Add New Todos</h2>

      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="text">New Todo: </label>
          <input type="text" required id="text" ref={titleInputRef}></input>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <button className="btn">Add Todo</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddTodoForm;
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a counter in the Form component. I would just call the handler with the text and let the "set state" function use the length of the current state array to create the next id, and return a new object at that point.

Comment: Yes @Andy, this is better. Updated the answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

In App.js, I have removed the update function and instead sent the `list` and `setList` as props to the `AddTodoForm` component.

```
import AddTodoForm from './components/AddTodoForm.js';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList.js';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const[list, setList] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>

      <AddTodoForm setList = {setList} list = {list}/>

      <h1>My Todos</h1>
        
      <TodoList todos={list} />    

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In `./components/AddTodoForm.js` add this peice of code inside the `AddTodoForm` function.

```
const update = ()=>{
    props.setList(datalist);
    console.log(props.list);
    console.log("The update function has run.")
}
```

I hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post my opinion to help you with my knowledge about React. In your above code, you cannot render updated state(list) to reflect TodoList component.

In hook, useEffect insteads 2 component lifecycles of class component idea. I mean, you should reflect useEffect with updated states(list).
useEffect is similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.
Like this:

```
enter code here
   useEfect(()=>{
      setList(dataList);
      console.log(list);
      console.log("update function has run.")
   },[list])
```